# How to make button work in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game, where I have created a Simple UI, and I want the play button to be an action whenever the player hit the play button.

> Here is an image: 
>   [image]
>
> Here is my code as well.

```
  //I JUST DID THIS. 

  let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg.png")

    bgImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

    bgImage.size = self.frame.size

    bgImage.name = "button1"

    self.addChild(bgImage)
```

Comment: Can send you my button code in Obj-c if you wish

Answer (score 1):

By default `isUserInteractionEnabled` is **false** so the touch on a scene child like your `bgImage` is, **by default**, a simple touch handled to the main (or parent) class (the object is here, exist but if you don't implement any action, you simply touch it)

If you set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to true on a `SKSpriteNode` subclass then the touch delegates will called inside this specific class. So, you can handle the touch for the sprite within its class. But **you don't need it**, this is not your case, you don't have subclassed your `bgImage`.

You should simply made in your scene:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "button1" {
            print("Tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

When I look to your image I suspected that your sprite `bg.png` was composed by background and also the button image: this is very uncomfortable, you should use only an image about your button and , if you want , make another sprite to show your background otherwise you touch ALL (background and button obviusly, not only the button as you needed..).

So, you should separate the image, for example your button could be this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add: `bgImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` ?

```
let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg.png")

bgImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

bgImage.size = self.frame.size

bgImage.name = "button1"
bgImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

self.addChild(bgImage)
```

Then:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "button1" {
            print("Tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly. BUT there is one mistake  when you tap outside the "Play button"  it still goes to my GameScene. which I dont want to. I want only when player taps on the play button.

Comment: Does that mean that the play button is just in the image, not in you game scene?? You can create a new sprite for the play button and give this function to it

Comment: I made the UI and input the "play button on it" if you meant like that which is yes.

Comment: what you mean define "input"?